# foo file in one Git branch and bar file in another

Tags: git

Can I have two different files in two branches with Git ?

I mean branch `master` have a file named `foo` and branch `new-master` a file named `bar`.

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-1.html It wouldn't hurt to look around for a bit yourself before posting a question here.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Who said I didn't search ? I  made some examples too but nothing worked. I *can* posts links too !

Comment: I see no examples.. we can't tell what you have tried if you don't share that information ;-)

Comment: @TimCastelijns well you are right :) but nothing worked for me and I thought a two sentence question will get easier a straight answer.

Comment: That's true. But that could also be an indication that this is information easily found elsewhere on the net, by checking out some of the examples on git-scm.com for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer - yes.

1. create the `new-master` branch from the old `master`:

   `git branch new-master`
2. in `master`, create `foo`:

   `touch foo
   git add foo
   git commit -m "added foo"`
3. switch over to `new-master`:

   `git checkout new-master`
4. create `bar`:

   `touch bar
   git add bar
   git commit -m "added bar"`

Comment: Now master has `foo` but new-master has both `foo` and `bar` while I want only bar.

Comment: you probably branched `new-master` after creating `foo` - this works perfectly on my env.